# HP DL360e gen8 - fans rev at 100% at all times

Tags: raid, fan, hp

I want to install proxmox on this machine To do this, I need to disable the b320i raid controller (disks are not detected during installation), but when I did this, the fans start working at 100% all the time, even without load.

Has anyone encountered this, how to solve it?

This only happens when the controller is disabled in the BIOS.

But I need this so as not to set up a hardware raid. I want to use ZFS raid